# std::vector alternative for C

Tags: c, arrays, stl, stdvector

I wonder if there is an alternative for the **std::vector in C?** I found [this implementation](http://codingrecipes.com/implementation-of-a-vector-data-structure-in-c) but it seems to contain some issues with memory reallocation.

Comment: which part of std::vector is bothering you that you're looking for an alternative implementation?

Comment: @Peyman: maybe he doesn't have a C++ compiler...

Comment: I am developing some code for the SmartXA2 based microcontroller and there is only a C compiler for it.

Comment: if this is an embedded system there may also be limits on malloc, memcpy and a limited amount of memory - you may be better off allocating a fixed maximum array at the start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While reading [C Array vs. C++ Vector](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/c-array-vs-c-vector/), I found an interesting implementation of a [simple vector container in C](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/kvec.h.html), which also includes **push/pop** operations. It's worth reading it!

Comment: Your link to the simple container is now broken.

Answer (score 10):

You can give **glib** and its [arrays](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.Array.html) (`GArray`) a try.

**glib** is actively maintained, cross platform, open source (LGPLv2+), and it doesn't stop on arrays/vectors. You also have hash tables, linked lists, queues and many other data structures.

Comment: I doubt glib is a good choice for an embedded system.

Comment: You are probably right. He didn't mention he was going to use it in an embedded system when I answered the question though...

Answer (score -1):

If you focus is on mathematics you can work with [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Vectors-and-Matrices.html), there have a more bare bones math centric concept.

Comment: This has no relation to `std::vector` whatsoever. It can't even grow.

Comment: Yes, it can't grow, thus avoiding reallocation issues.