# Fill a 2d array from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays

So i have a 20 x 20 array, and its all filled with -1.
I also have an input.txt which contains some numbers, for example :
    2,3
    5,6

How can i fill my array so that `array[0][0]` will be `2`,
`array[0][1]` will be `3`, `array[1][0]` will be `5`, `array[1][1]` will be `6`, and every other element will be -1.

I've tried with a for loop thats using fscanf until there is a new line, but that won't work.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: "I've tried with a for loop thats using fscanf until there is a new line, but that won't work." --> Post that code and explain how  it did not work.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: How did https://stackoverflow.com/q/53436800/2410359 not work for you?  That question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried with a for loop thats using fscanf until there is a new line, but that won't work.

Variations on `fscanf(in, "%d,%d\n", &x, &y)`, as in OP's [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53436800/2410359), fail to detect end-of-line.  The `'\n'` in the format will match any white-space on input including `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'`,etc.

Simplistic usage of `fscanf(..., "%d",...)` can readily fail as `"%d"` will consume all leading white-space with no discrimination between `'\n'` and other white-spaces.

> How can i fill my array ...

Although possible to use `fscanf()` to solve this task, consider **fgets(), strtol()**.

The best approach is to use `fgets()` to reach a *line*: all characters up to and including the one final  `'\n'`.  Then use `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, etc. to read the integers.

`long` integers and spacing each needs reasonable less than 21 characters.  To accommodate extra leading zeros spacing, etc, let use 2x the anticipated size needs.

```
#define CHAR_PER_NUMBER 21
#define NUM_PER_LINE 20
#define LINE_NUM 20
#define LINE_SIZE (NUM_PER_LINE * CHAR_PER_NUMBER * 2)

long array[LINE_NUM][NUM_PER_LINE];

// read data
for (int i = 0; i < LINE_NUM; i++) {
  char buf[LINE_SIZE + 1]; // +1: room for the appended the null character
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) == NULL) {
    buf[0] = '\0';
  }
  // Now parse the line
  char *p = buf;
  for (int j = 0; j < NUM_PER_LINE; j++) {
    char *endptr;
    array[i][j] = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
    if (p == endptr) {
      array[i][j] = -1; // no conversion  
    }
    p = endptr; // advance to the next number
  }
}
```

Additional concerns including handling  pathological long lines, values outside the `long` range, I/O error handling and efficiency details.

Should input consists of text representing floating-point, a more generous max size per value is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "end of file"(eof), where m and n are the rows and columns

```
for (i = 0; i < m && !feof(input); i++)
  for (j = 0; j < n && !feof(input); j++)
  fscanf(input, "%f", &a[i][j]);
```

If the size of the array (m and n) is also given in the file write an if condition before

```
if (!feof(input))
  fscanf(input, "%d %d", &m, &n);
for (i = 0; i < m && !feof(input); i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n && !feof(input); j++)
      fscanf(input, "%f", &a[i][j]);
```

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359) is a useful read here.  Better to check the return value of `fscanf()`.